# Iterating a matrix according to line equation

Tags: matlab

If I have a line equation y=mx+b and a matrix M, is there any easy way to iterate all the elements in M that the line is passing through them?
If not, I'll be glad if you tell me an algorithm to do this.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: By easy I mean any matlab library function. I tried some complicated stepping - starting from the intersection of the line with the matrix frame and then making a step x=x+1 or y=y+1, depends on the distance from the next point from previous point.

Comment: Yuval, what do you mean by 'iterate all the elements in M that the line is passing through them'? What is dimensionality of matrix M?

Comment: M is 2-D. I mean that if size(M) is [Y X] (Y rows, X columns), then suppose we have a graph y=mx+b, put M in the graph in such a way that the indexes of M correspond to x and y values on the axises. I try to code computer vision algorithm, that's why the line will pass through M, and I want to iterate the pixels in the photo(matrix M) that it goes through them.

Comment: You wish to select rows from M (points) that lies on the line ax + b = y? 
Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly.

```
Y = M(:, 1);
X = M(:, 2);

A = [X ones(size(X))];
R = A \ Y;
a = R(1);
b = R(2);
```

Comment: This is least squares, right?  I did not mean that. I reposted the question clearier, it is related to image processing so I explained it better now. Thanks!